# What does it mean when a bound is sharp?

Tags: definition

I've been reading this paper about the maximum size of digraphs. The author mentions that one of the digraph has a sharp bound. What does it mean when a bound is sharp?

Comment: In $a\le b$, $b$ is an upper bound. It is said sharp if the equality $a=b$ indeed occurs, so that you cannot find a lower upper bound. For instance, $\sin x\le1$ is sharp; $\sin x\le2$ is true but not sharp.

Comment: Just one addition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds#Tight_bounds The bound is called *sharp* if equality holds for at least one value of x; The bound is called *tight* if no smaller/larger value is a bound. See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/what-is-an-asymptotically-tight-upper-bound

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Sharp" Inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253778/sharp-inequalities)

Answer (score 13):

Let's suppose that $X$ is suitably closed, otherwise we have to work with suprema. We say $y$ is a sharp upper bound for $X$ if $y\geq x$ for all $x \in X$ **and** there exists an $x_0 \in X$ such that $y=x_0$.

That is, $y$ is the best possible upper bound that can be found.

Comment: Then can we take it as a generalization of the concept "supremum"?

Comment: There's no generlisation about it. A supremum of a set *is* a sharp upper bound of that set.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, let $A=[0,1]$. Then $1$ is a sharp upper bound for the elements in $A$, since $1\ge \text{all } a\in A$. The numbers $2$ or $3$ or any number $>1$ are also upper bounds, however not sharp. A sharp bound cannot be improved upon, since there must at least one case where the condition holds with equality.