# On the definition of sharp bounds for errors measurements

Tags: terminology, upper-lower-bounds

Questions on the definition of sharpness in the context of bounds and inequalities have already been asked in this site, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985794/342439) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1253778/342439). However I am interested in the specific case where sharp bounds are derived for some error measurement.

Let us consider some function $r:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which can be interpreted as the size of some error which we are trying to bound; moreover there exists $x^\star\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $r(x^\star)=0$ that is the error is zero at $x^\star$. This is the case for example when approximating a function $f(h)$ around zero by using its Taylor expansion $f(0)+f^\prime(0)h$: when the shift $h$ becomes null then the value coincides with the approximation.

I don't have any reference at hand but when reading papers where an error is measured, I often find theorems or propositions where the author(s) have established a "*sharp bound*" (also referred to as "*sharp estimate*") for the error; this has the form of some inequality. So let us assume we have found a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:
\begin{align}
& r(x)\leq g(x), \quad \forall\ x\in\mathbb{R} \tag{1a}\\
& r(x^\star)=g(x^\star) \tag{1b}
\end{align}
According to the definitions on sharpness (see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2252173/342439)), the function $g$ provides a sharp upper bound on the error. Yet because we have assumed $r(x^\star)=0$, we can always find a constant $C$ such that $Cg(x)$ also satisfies $(1)$ because $Cg(x^\star)=C\times0=r(x^\star)$. Therefore the "sharpness" of the bound can be arbitrarily widened or tightened.

**Would the above be still considered a sharp bound (in the context of error measurement)? Does a sharp bound for error estimates mean something else?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't have $0<C<1$ where $r(x^*) \leq Cg(x^*)$, yet $r(x^*) \leq g(x^*)$, then the only solution is to have $r(x^*) = g(x^*)$.

What I'm trying to illustrate is that the problem with picking and choosing which $x$ you inspect and expecting the inequality to be airtight, is that you effectively force the LHS to be equal to RHS for every $x$. Which is no longer a bound, it is an equality.

A bound means that for every $x$ (or $x_1,x_2,...$ in the case of multiple parameters), the inequality holds, and a bound being tight means for SOME $x$ (or $x_1,x_2,...$), we have equality.

For your specific question, no, we cannot simply make $g(x)$ tighter by a factor of $C$ since $g(x)$ may be non-zero at points other than $x^*$. For example:

[image]

Comment: I understand your point but not sure I follow the example you use in the first paragraph $-$ by assumption we always have $r(x^*)=Cg(x^*)$ for any $C$ because $r(x^*)=g(x^*)=0$.

Comment: right. so, that's true for $x^*$, but we can't expect that to be true for every x

Comment: sorry, my initial picture was a bound in the wrong direction, I've updated it, maybe that helps

Comment: Thank you @ScottHahn.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what the value is, notice that $\not \exists f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $r(x) \le f(x) < g(x),\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$—otherwise, $r(x^\star) < g(x^\star)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I believe in this case the strict and loose inequalities should be inverted? The point being that there is no “uniformly better” bound $f$ (ie $f<g$) otherwise $0=r(x^*)\leq f(x^*)<g(x^*)$ that is $g(x^*)>0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @MorrisFletcher: corrected.